# How to scale up a model in a training dataset to cover all aspects of training data

Tags: machine-learning, rare-events

I was asked in an interview to solve a use case with the help of machine learning. I have to use a Machine Learning algorithm to identify fraud from transactions. My training dataset has lets say 100,200 transactions, out of which 100,000 are legal transactions and 200 are fraud.

I cannot use the dataset as a whole to make the model because it would be a biased dataset and the model would be a very bad one.

Lets say for example I take a sample of 200 good transactions which represent the dataset well(good transactions), and the 200 fraud ones and make the model using this as the training data.

The question I was asked was that how would I scale up the 200 good transactions to the whole data set of 100,000 good records so that my result can be mapped to all types of transactions. I have never solved this kind of a scenario so I did not know how to approach it.

Any kind of guidance as to how I can go about it would be helpful.